# Postgresql LATERAL vs INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, lateral

*JOIN*

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.id, Count(*) AS Count
    FROM b
    GROUP BY b.id ) AS b ON b.id = a.id;
```

*LATERAL*

```
SELECT *
FROM a,
  LATERAL (
    SELECT Count(*) AS Count
    FROM b
    WHERE a.id = b.id ) AS b;
```

I understand that here join will be computed once and then merge with the main request vs the request for each FROM.

---

It seems to me that if join will rotate a few rows to one frame then it will be more efficient but if it will be 1 to 1 then LATERAL - I think right?

Comment: The several or one rows is not efficient to LATERAL. LATERAL is more efficient when b contains many rows that are not associated with the selected rows from a.

Comment: stop, but not the point, in order to be united? you say that they will be more effective if they are not bound - then the meaning of the request is lost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you right you are asking which of the two statements is more efficient.

You can test that yourself using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`, and I guess that the answer depends on the data:

- If there are few rows in `a`, the `LATERAL` join will probably be more efficient if there is an index on `b(id)`.
- If there are many rows in `a`, the first query will probably be more efficient, because it can use a hash or merge join.

Comment: Hi - I tested - if I have 10 records of the upper level and for each level I have 200 000 entries-because of INNER I got 2.5 seconds to do this, After that I made 200,000 records of the first and second levelLATERAL cope for 3 minute

Comment: Sure, makes sense. As I said, it depends on your data.